# Get label expression to dynamically access field used for Graduated symbology

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology

This is my first task in QGIS.

I have 38 variables that I would want to produce map for each  as shown below

[image]

I have discovered easy ways of achieving that in a QGIS project. However, the challenge arises in automation of labels on the map since am using Rule based Labelling that utilizes use of expressions. Specifically, as demonstrated

[image]

In the example above, the name of the indicator is ***input data_1_ant_care_skilled_provider*** and am wondering whether there's a way to code it to refer to the variable selected under symbology as shown below

[image]

Comment: Indeed, not clear your question. With "variables" you seem to mean attributes. So you apply a graduated symbology and you want to label the polygons by the same value used for graduated symbols? So what I don't understand why you don't simply use the same value as for symbology. No need for rule based labeling?

Comment: @Babel tanks for your question - the reason I am using the rule based labelling is because some of the units are too small thus I end up using callouts and in others I use numbers that I reference them in a table. Hope this is clear

Comment: You can access some variables of the symbology like colour or I think size, but as far as I'm aware, the actual field or expression used for categorising your symbology isn't stored as a variable that can be easily accessible using QGIS expressions, you may have to use Python to create a custom function that you can then apply to your label expression.

Comment: @StephenOkiya I still don't understand the problem. Can you share a sample project with dummy data to see what you have? Otherwise difficult to help

Comment: @Babel I have included the desired map. You'll notice that the labels are of 3 different types - name + value at the centroid, name + value as callouts and the attribute table. I use the rule based labelling to achieve this. However, I am looking for a way to refer to the variables in symbology so that it can ease my work. Hope its clear

Comment: @she_weeds thanks so much for your thoughts

Comment: The third part (attribute table) is better done in print layouts, adding a new element for the table as this is easier. For the two kinds of labels, I would rather use placement settings. As far as I understand the problem, the placement of the labels is the problem: sometimes inside the polygons, in other cases outside (when there is not enough space). So the question still seem to be very misleading or I still don't understand the very problem you want to solve.

Comment: The question is whether it is possible to dynamically reference the "Value" in Symbology in an expression in Labels

Comment: "value" is an attribute? Or where does it come from?

Comment: As I mentioned am new to QGIS so am not sure. What am referring to is demonstrated in the third image

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand your question: what does automatization of labels have to do with graduated styling? What variable are you speaking about? Please have a look at [tour] to understand how this site works. Than make yourself comfortable with GIS terminology. "Attribute" is a basic concept in GIS and as long as you don't understand the very basics, probably best to stick to some tutorials before trying more complicated tasks.  See e.g. https://youtu.be/kCnNWyl9qSE or https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/index.html or https://locatepress.com/book/dq32

Answer (score 2):

I'm just writing this as an answer now, but I think it's clear what you are trying to do:

1. You want to have a new map to represent each data category (=field or column) as shown in your 3rd screenshot. e.g. `input data_14_w_2plus_partners`, `input data_15_w_neither_spouse_live`, `input data_16_w_mean_partners` etc.
2. You visualise each data category by changing the `Value` in the graduated symbology for this layer, so for example using the drop down list to change the field from `input data_14_w_2plus_partners` to `input data_15_w_neither_spouse_live`.
3. Right now, you have the field hard-coded into the label expression as shown in your second screenshot, so no matter what field you use for the symbology it will only show the % value for `input data_1_ant_care_skilled_provider`.
4. You are looking for a way to write the label expression to automatically pick up whatever field you are currently using in your graduated symbology, so that when you change the symbology field from `input data_1_ant_care_skilled_provider` to `input data_14_w_2plus_partners`, the labels for each feature will also show the % for `input data_14_w_2plus_partners` without you having to manually change them.

As far as I'm aware, there is no inbuilt function in Field Calculator for QGIS to access the field/category you have selected from the dropdown list as in screenshot 3, and store it as a variable that you can then use in your labelling.

So you would have to manually update the label expression each time (I would recommend storing each combination of label expression and symbology as a map theme so you can easily go back and forth between different ones).

Manually updating the labels each time is a pain, but I don't think there is any way to automate it without using Python. Hopefully this answer will attract people who will understand what you are trying to do and come up with an easy solution.

---

Please note the process isn't as automatic as you may think; with step 2 above, every time you change the field by which you categorise your graduated symbology, you must press 'Classify' so that the symbology updates appropriately. The symbology does not instantly change to reflect the new field's values as soon as you select it using the 'Value' drop down box.

See below for example - when I change the field from `PERTR15MPL` (percentage coverage of trees >15 m tall) to `PERANYTREE` (percentage tree cover regardless of size), you would expect the values to increase significantly and for there to be more green areas. But the symbology doesn't change at all until I press Classify.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback. I sincerely appreciate